# ってやつ vs というもの difference

Tags: expressions

In the novel I am reading, MC is often using ってやつ, I am wondering about the difference between it and というもの.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## 日本語

personanongrataさんは日本語｛にほんご｝が良｛よ｝く分｛わ｝かる方｛かた｝だと思｛おも｝いますので日本語｛にほんご｝で回答｛かいとう｝します。

「ってやつ」と「というもの」とはかなり違｛ちが｝います。

(1)

- 下品｛げひん｝な口語｛こうご｝であり、男｛おとこ｝言葉｛ことば｝ --- ってやつ
- 普通｛ふつう｝ --- というもの

(2)

- 人物｛じんぶつ｝を指｛さ｝す --- ってやつ
- 物｛もの｝を指｛さ｝す --- というもの

確｛たし｝かに、「というもの」を漢字｛かんじ｝で書｛か｝くと「という物｛もの｝」と「という者｛もの｝」という二通｛ふたとお｝りの書｛か｝き表｛あらわ｝し方｛かた｝があり、前者｛ぜんしゃ｝は「物」、後者｛こうしゃ｝は「人」を表｛あらわ｝しますが、「者」は普通｛ふつう｝の言｛い｝い方｛かた｝ではなく、人を見下｛みくだ｝した言い方です。従｛したが｝って、普通に「というもの」と言ったり書｛か｝いたりするときには、「という物」を意味｛いみ｝します。なお、「というもの」の代｛か｝わりに「人」を指す場合｛ばあい｝は、「という人」と言います。

---

#### 加筆訂正

私の回答に対してbroccoli forestさんから次の２つのコメントをいただきました。

> （Ａ） 「やつ」を物を指して使うのも一般的だと思いますが…
> （Ｂ） 「幸福って**やつ**はきっと傍｛そば｝にある　自転車こいで行ける所に」（は、「やつ」が「物」を表す「って**やつ**」を含む文例だと思います 【括弧内はmackygooが勝手に追加した文言】）

（Ａ）、（Ｂ）ともに私が最初の回答で「やつ」は「人」と言い切ったことに対する再考を促すコメントだと判断しました。
いずれのコメントに対してもコメントで返答しようと取り掛かりましたが、回答が長くなりそうなので、こうして「EDIT」で再考することにしました。「EDIT」は日本語では「編集」ではなく、意味的には「追記」あるいは「訂正」のいずれもが合いそうなので、「加筆訂正」としました。
「加筆訂正」のついでに、「というもの」にも、「という者」という意味で使う場合が見つかりましたので、これについても述べます。

#### その１ 「やつ」は、物を指すか

単独では「物」を指さないと判断しております。
それは、次の２つの例で判断しました。

（１）　やつはどこに居る？　*Where is he?*
（２）　やつはどこに有る？　*Where is the thing?*

「居る」と「有る」は、「人」と「物」の存在を各々区別するために使われます。また、（１）、（２）ともに「やつ」を規定する（to specify）修飾子（modifier）がありません。すなわち「やつ」が単独で使われています。
粗野な（rude/coarse）言い方かどうかは別にすると、（１）は自然な日本語ですが、（２）は明らかに不自然です。
従って、「やつ」は単独では「物」を指さないと判断しました。

「やつ」は実際には辞書でどのように定義されているのでしょうか。手許{てもと}の国語辞典で調べますと次のようになっております。

> やつ【奴】
> ❶（名詞）
> ①《俗語》人・物をののしったり、または親しんで言う語。「ばかな**やつ**」
> ②「もの」「こと」をぞんざいに言う語。「大きい**やつ**をくれ」
> ❷（代名詞）《俗語》他称の人代名詞。第三者を指す乱暴な言い方。まれに、親しみをこめて用いることもある。あいつ。

別の辞書では次のように定義されています。

> やつ【奴】
> ❶（名詞）（「やっこ」の略）
> ①人を卑しめていい、または目下のものを親しんでいう語。鳥獣を卑しめていうこともある。
> ②物事を乱暴に言う語。「こっちの**やつ**をくれ」
> ❷（代名詞）（三人称）卑しめていうとき、また無遠慮にいうときに用いる。あやつ。きゃつ。「**やつ**のしわざだ」

２つの辞書ともに、「やつ」として、三人称に対する人称代名詞という定義があります。これは、英語でいうとhe/sheに相当します。従って、単独で「やつ」を使う場合は、三人称代名詞として使われるので、「人」を指す（１）が自然に聞こえるのだと思います。

#### その２ 「やつ」は、修飾子があると、文脈次第で「物」にも「人」にもなる。

「やつ」単独でなく、修飾する語が存在する場合の例で考えてみます。
例として、「大きい**やつ**」「こっちの**やつ**」「黒い**やつ**」を考えてみます。いずれも、「人」としても「物」としても解釈できます。従って、更に判断材料が存在すると次のようにいずれを意味しているかが明確になります。

（３）物を指す：「大きい**やつ**を取ってくれ」「こっちの**やつ**は安いだろう」「黒い**やつ**は明日着る」
（４）人を指す：「大きい**やつ**は後ろに下がれ」「こっちの**やつ**は向こうへ行け」「黒い**やつ**は誰だ」

#### その３　「ってやつ」「というもの」に話を戻して再度考えてみます。

質問者が提示した「ってやつ」と「というもの」というフレーズは、実際には「〇〇ってやつ」「〇〇というやつ」というフレーズの部分ですので、「やつ」に対して「〇〇」という部分が修飾子になります。従って、「その２」の検討により、「やつ」が「物」としても「人」としても成り立つことになります。では、同じような意味の文例を使ってどのような時に成り立つのか見て行きます

#### その４ 「ってやつ」と「というもの」が共に「人」を指す例

最初の回答で「ってやつ」は人を指すが、「というもの」は物を指すと言いましたが、**第三者に対して自分・身内・家族や仲間を指し示す時**に、「という者」という"へりくだった表現 *expressed in humble language*"を使う例が見つかりました。但し、「というもの」が「という者」として「人」を指す言葉として使われるのは、**この例のように特殊な場合だと言えます**。通常は第三者を指し示すときには、最初の回答にあったように、「という者」ではなく、「という人」と言い換えることが一般的です。

"*When a person named Yamada will visit here, please let me know by all means*."
（５） 「山田ってやつが訪ねてきたら、是非ともここへ連絡願いてえ。」
（６） 「山田という者が訪ねて来たら、是非ともここへご連絡願います。」

#### その５ 「ってやつ」「というもの」が共に「物」を指す例

"*I'm sure so-called happiness is near you in a place where you can go by bicycle*."
（７） 幸福ってやつはきっと傍｛そば｝にある　自転車こいで行ける所に
（８） 幸福というものはきっと傍にあるもんだよ　自転車こいで行ける所にな

（７）はbroccoli forestさんがコメントで紹介してくださった「[３年Ｂ組金八先生](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinpachi-sensei)（第５シリーズ）」の主題歌の歌詞の一部であることがわかりました。Wikipediaによると、「３２年間も続いたテレビドラマシリーズ。日本の学園ドラマの金字塔（a monumental achievement/work）と称される作品である。中学校の教員である坂本金八が、学級担任をしている3年B組内に起こる様々な問題を体当たりで解決していく。そんな彼の姿に心を打たれた生徒たちが考えを改め、人間として成長していく様子を描く。」とあります。
武田鉄矢が熱血教師を演じる有名なドラマですが、この主題歌にある「幸福ってやつ」は、日常的に使われる表現でなく、意気に感じている人間が若干背伸びをしつつ、高揚感をもって言ったセリフだと判断できます。（８）の表現は、その辺りのニュアンスがでるように創作してみました。明治時代の書生が言うようなセリフかなというのが率直な感想です。ちょっとこそばゆい感じがします。武田鉄矢さんやドラマを茶化しているつもりはありませんが、「幸福ってやつ」の「ってやつ」はには、上記辞書でいう「親しんで言う語」に近いのでしょうが、もう一つぴったりしません。敢えていうと、「親しみと、この言葉を口にした人の恥ずかしさが込もった言い方」でしょうか。「幸福」という「物」以外にも、「人」にも使えそうです。むしろ抽象名詞の「幸福」の方が例外に近く、仮に奥さんの名前が百合子ならご主人が百合子さんの気配りに気づいたときに「百合子ってやつは」あるいは「お前ってやつは」と言いそうです。
「幸福ってやつは」は、「ってやつ」が「物」を表す事例として十分なものですが、金八先生というドラマの中の特殊な状況に沿った歌詞であり一般的な用法かと言うとやや厳しいと言うのが私の判断です。

次のものも同じような意味の文で「やつ」が「物」を表す例です。
"*I would like to drink a drink named Romanée-Conti once*."
（９） ロマネ・コンティってやつ、一度は飲んでみてえ。
（１０） ロマネ・コンティというものを一度は飲んでみたい。
この例では、名前を知っているか聞いたことはあるが、実態を知らない物に対して使うのだろうと想定します。「ロマネ・コンティってやつ」の「やつ」はどういう意味なのでしょうか。私は、話者が背伸びして言っているように感じます。
「おい親仁｛おやじ｝、獺祭｛だっさい｝っての一杯[注]｛つ｝いでくれ！」は、競馬で大儲けした酒呑みが言いそうなセリフです。私には、（９）は（７）より自然であり、一般に使われそうに感じます。

以上いくつかの例を通じて、broccoli forestさんから頂いた２つのコメント（Ａ）と（Ｂ）について見てきましたが、個々の検討結果が示すように、その多くは、一般的ではなく特例的ですが、最後の（９）や獺祭の例は、日本語として自然だなあと感じました。

最後になりましたが、大変勉強になりました。broccoli forestさんありがとうございます。

## English

"ってやつ" and "というもの" are not so much alike.

(1)

- impolite colloquialism and male expression --- ってやつ
- normal --- というもの

(2)

- to indicate a person --- ってやつ
- to indicate a thing --- というもの

Indeed, there are two ways to describe "というもの" with kanji, "という物" and "という者". The former expression represents "物 *thing*" and the latter represents "人 *person*", but "者" is not a normal way of describing a person, but a way of looking down on the person. Therefore, when saying or writing "もの" as usual, it means "things". If you want to refer to a "person" instead of a "thing", you should say "人 *person*" as in "という人" instead of "という者".

Comment: 「やつ」を物を指して使うのも一般的だと思いますが… https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6058/7810

Comment: @broccoli forest:>「やつ」を物を指して使うのも: 言うことはあるのは知っていますが、人を指していうほど**一般的ではない**ですよね。目をつむって「 **やつ** はっ！」というのを聞いた時何を思いますか。私は、１０中８，９はろくでもない男を指していると思います。

Comment: @broccoli forest: 「やつ」単独では「人」を指します。「物」を指す場合には何か冠をかぶせるような気がします。「例のやつ」、「いつものやつ」。この場合は、「人」ではないですね。ところで「あやつ」は人ですね。「そんなやつ」は、多分「人」ですね。「ってやつ」に先行する言葉を想像すると「山田ってやつ」はありそうですが、「おでんってやつはもうコンビニで出てるって！？」というのはなくはないですが、「山田ってやつ」より自然でないような気がします。

Comment: @mackygoo 「幸福ってやつはきっと傍にある　自転車こいで行ける所に」 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tKaYgVEY1g