# What does ってやつか mean?

Tags: words, song-lyrics

I was watching a music video (name: 思想犯). I've been going through the song and I stumbled upon this ってやつか. What does it mean here, it's not って奴か. I've found a post here about ってやつ vs というもの but I don't think they're the same.

[ってやつ vs というもの difference](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/53327/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%84%E3%81%A4-vs-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE-difference)

I don't know about punctuation, so here it is formatted like this:

> 認められたい 愛したい これが夢**ってやつか**
> 何もしなくても叶えよ 早く 僕を満たしてくれ
> 他人に優しい世間にこの妬みがわかるものか
> いつも誰かを殴れる機会を探してる

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *is* って奴か in kanji. [奴【やつ】](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%A5%B4-1) can be a pronoun for both a person and an inanimate object. 奴 sounds masculine and rough. って is short for という here.

> これが夢ってやつか。
> ≈ これが夢というものか。
>
> This is what people call a dream, huh?
> This is what dream means, huh?

And this これ refers to what has been just mentioned (認められたい 愛したい).

Comment: What do you mean by "sounds masculine" -- that it refers to someone/something masculine or that someone masculine would use this word?

Comment: @a20 Yes, so-called [男性語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%94%B7%E6%80%A7%E8%AA%9E) or 男言葉 (that doesn't mean women don't use 奴, of course).

Comment: I think nowadays the usage of ってやつ (referring inanimate object) is more "colloquial" than "masculine".